# Why is my categorical variable split up into separate variables in my regression model in r

Tags: r, lm

I'm creating a multivariate model in R right now.

When I plot categorical variables into the lm() function and check the summary() output, my categorical variable gets split up into a beta coefficient for each option inside of the variable.

When I checked the data type it came back as a factor variable,
[here is the output of summary to visualize the issue easier.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMimZ.png)

Comment: Each category is modeled as the difference between it and a reference category (the intercept). Iif you 5 categories, you need 4 coefficients to model those 5 means.

Comment: I'm finding it hard understanding this from a more traditional numeric variable regression. I figured the variable would have a constant number next to the coefficient to fit for whatever the beta value would be.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471095/difference-between-categorical-variables-factors-and-dummy-variables?rq=1) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837025/understanding-why-linear-regression-isnt-treating-my-categorical-variable-as-ex?rq=1). R basically automatically expands your factor into binary dummy variables.

Comment: If you want a global "test" for your factor (as in an ANOVA) you can use for example `drop1` that basically compare the model with and without the factor as explanatory variable. For example :  `m <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris) ; drop1(m, test = "F")`

Comment: In R, it's also common to `car::Anova` to get a traditional anova table (with type ii sum of squares by default).  To use @Gilles ' example:  `if(!require(car)){install.packages("car")}; m = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris); library(car); Anova(m)`

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell, since Regression analysis requires numerical variables; when a regression is performed with a categorical variable in a regression model, each category of the variable is transformed into a separate variable aka 'dummy' variable. When a dummy variable is 1, it means a categorical variable belongs to that category represented by this dummy variable.

This link here explains nicely how regression with categorical variables is performed in R :

http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/163-regression-with-categorical-variables-dummy-coding-essentials-in-r/