# Why are variables in GLM being split into multiple output variables

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I have input for glm that looks like

```
BMI  $grp PRS  age  gene
24.2 1    3.0  77   0.0
33.8 1    4.0  89   0.0
30.3 1    7.0  58   0.0
```

I’m inputting this into `glm` : `mylogit <- glm($grp ~ BMI + PRS + age + gene, data = data, family = 'binomial')`

Where `$grp` and `gene` are categorical variables,

And the output looks like:

```
[1]  "    data = data)",
[2]  "",
[3]  "Deviance Residuals: ",
[4]  "    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  ",
[5]  "-1.6969  -1.1797   0.7726   1.0553   1.9250  ",
[6]  "",
[7]  "Coefficients:",
[8]  "              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  ",
[9]  "(Intercept)  -3.036889   2.000203  -1.518   0.1289  ",
[10] "BMI           0.007068   0.027942   0.253   0.8003  ",
[11] "PRS          -0.201259   0.125757  -1.600   0.1095  ",
[12] "age           0.056960   0.022722   2.507   0.0122 *",
[13] "gene1        -0.306879   0.577173  -0.532   0.5949  ",
[14] "gene2        14.642064 882.743409   0.017   0.9868  ",
```

My question is unrelated to [Why is my categorical variable split up into separate variables in my regression model in r](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438599/why-is-my-categorical-variable-split-up-into-separate-variables-in-my-regression)

I've also looked at http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/163-regression-with-categorical-variables-dummy-coding-essentials-in-r/ but this doesn't show variables being split

For the formula `glm(formula = Deceased ~ PRS + age + BMI + sex, family = "binomial", data = data)` I won't get `sex` but rather just `sex1` which I don't understand.

```
> with(data, table($grp, gene))
        gene
$grp  0  1  2
       0 51  8  0
       1 67  7  1
```

My question is why is gene being split into gene1 and gene2?  What is the significance of either of these? Which variable should be reported for gene?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dummy+coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gene is a factor with three levels. You can confirm this by checking `levels(factor(data$gene))`. The reference level is rolled into the intercept term, and the coefficients corresponding to the other two levels are displayed next to `gene1` and `gene2`.

The model fit looks unreliable due to the exceedingly high standard error on `gene2`. I suggest taking a look at your response by each level of gene using

```
with(data, table($grp, gene))
```

Comment: I've added the output of `with` to the question (comments don't allow for good code snippets) how can I interpret the output?

Comment: This is a contingency table of the response by the levels of gene. Look at the last row: it says that you have only one observation of the response for `gene2`. That's causing the wonkiness of your standard errors and coefficient estimates for that group (and possibly a glm warning)

Info on contingency tables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20a%20contingency%20table,%2C%20engineering%2C%20and%20scientific%20research.